# VAE ( variational autoencoder) for timeseries anomaly detection ,

Tags: keras, variational-autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am implementing VAE based anomaly detection for multivariate timeseries using keras,
I have ELBO (Evidence lower bound) which is combination of

$$-\ D_{KL}\left({\ q}_\varphi\left(z\middle| x^i\right)\parallel p_\theta\left(z\right)\ \right)\ +\ \ E_{q_\varphi(z|x^i)}\left[\log{p_\theta\left(x\middle| z\right)}\right]$$

The loss function is combination of minimizing the **KL[Q(z|x)|p(z)]** and maximizing **log [P(X|z)]**
how do I implement the above loss function for the multivariate timeseries of shape (batch_size,time_steps,features) using Tensorflow ?
appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi yeah i am basically struggling with  the implementation part of Loss function for VAE and my data is multivariate timeseries data.